# Recharts Pie chart .. can pie slice move when selected?

Tags: reactjs, charts, pie-chart

React Recharts Pie chart - can a pie slice move when selected?
I need to move a slice in **React Recharts - pie chart** on a mouse-over event. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: please provice a code sample fof your current project and what you hsave tried to solve your problem :) you can find more tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by using the `Pie` [activeShape](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Pie#activeShape) render-prop, in combination with the `Sector` component.

[Here is a simplified example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-answer-61684688-0q4un?file=/src/App.js:437-1001) which demonstrates this:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { ResponsiveContainer, PieChart, Pie, Sector } from "recharts";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Group A",
    value: 400
  },
  {
    name: "Group B",
    value: 300
  },
  {
    name: "Group C",
    value: 300
  },
  {
    name: "Group D",
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: "Group E",
    value: 278
  },
  {
    name: "Group F",
    value: 189
  }
];

const renderActiveShape = props => {
  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const {
    cx,
    cy,
    innerRadius,
    outerRadius,
    startAngle,
    endAngle,
    midAngle
  } = props;
  const sin = Math.sin(-RADIAN * midAngle);
  const cos = Math.cos(-RADIAN * midAngle);
  const sx = cx + (outerRadius - 40) * cos;
  const sy = cy + (outerRadius - 40) * sin;
  return (
    <Sector
      cx={sx}
      cy={sy}
      innerRadius={innerRadius}
      outerRadius={outerRadius}
      startAngle={startAngle}
      endAngle={endAngle}
      fill="red"
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
  const onMouseOver = useCallback((data, index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
  }, []);
  const onMouseLeave = useCallback((data, index) => {
    setActiveIndex(null);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={250}>
      <PieChart height={250}>
        <Pie
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          data={data}
          dataKey="value"
          nameKey="name"
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          outerRadius={50}
          fill="#8884d8"
          activeShape={renderActiveShape}
          onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
          onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
        />
      </PieChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}
```